# Is there an optimum RAM configuration to use for FME Desktop?

Tags: fme-form, performance

I have a couple of workstations with 32GB RAM where fme.exe processes often exceed 25GB, if its available.  And I'm looking to possibly add a 3rd workstation.  I noticed in an FME2014 beta build some performance degredation for fme.exe processes using large amounts of memory. Log file had tons of `ResourceManager: Optimizing Memory Usage.  Please wait...`  statements, so I think it was spending more time **optimizing** memory than it was using it.  But I'm not in a position where I can test a newer betas and different releases at the moment.

Do production releases of FME Desktop work best on a certain RAM configuration (or is there an optimum range).

Would FME benefit from 128GB of RAM? Or would there be issues?

I'm intentionally leaving versions out of this question because I'm interested in any experience with FME Desktop with a RAM configuration higher than mine.

*FWIW, it's really cool that I get to ask a question about a software that can use 25GB.*

Comment: I think is more to do with the transformers used in the workspace (in multi-core chips) from experience as the parallel processes can be split up and spawn new fme.exe's and cut processing time down significantly.  http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Parallel-Processing

Comment: If I add a 3rd workstation, it would be a 64-bit Windows OS.

Comment: It's also cool that you would have the option to have 128GB of RAM at your disposal.

Comment: @ChadCooper: maybe 128GB...if it makes sense! Kind of why I am asking the question.  But I definitely would like to see what FME with that much RAM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there's an optimum amount of memory. FME will work with whatever is available. The optimizing memory usage message means we've got to the point where memory is starting to get low and we're having to reorganize. So the more memory you have (or the smaller the amount of data) the fewer of these messages you should see.

Having said that, if you've a workspace that has many more of these messages in 2014 then please do report it to us through the formal support channels. If you can include the workspace (and data if possible) then we can do some testing and make sure we aren't slower than before. We can even add it to our testsuite, so each build is tested against your personal scenario!

You can get in touch with the support team at: http://www.safe.com/support/support-resources/request-support/