# Is there a way to constrain an FME.exe to certain amount of RAM?

Tags: fme-form, performance

If I have FME Desktop running on a workstation with a large amount of RAM (e.g. 128 GB), is there a way to constrain an FME.exe process to a certain amount of RAM (e.g. 48GB)?

This question is inspired by my closely related question:
[Is there an optimum RAM configuration to use for FME Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77957/is-there-an-optimum-ram-configuration-to-use-for-fme-desktop)

Comment: What Operating System?, as FME support Mac, Windows and Linux now (32/64bit).

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx is a good tool to see more in depth information on the process (.dlls used)

Comment: @Mapperz--Agreed, I have that exe on every workstation!  But I'm looking at a possible 3rd workstation unlike my other 2 (RAM-wise), so its hypothetical at this point.  But it will be a Windows OS - 64 bit.

Comment: Check with Safe Support. Maybe they have a solution for you ! ;)