# Can FME Desktop (node-locked) be installed on an Amazon EC2 or VPC instance?

Tags: fme-form, amazon-ec2, legal

I did do some searching in the FME help and the legal notices, but I'm not getting any hits (probably due to vocabulary). Are there any legal restrictions for FME Desktop that would prevent me from installing onto an EC2 or VPC Amazon instance?  I'm not sure if (or how much) that would compete against the FME Cloud offering.  I'm mostly interested for test and evaluation, but I am also curious if anyone is using an EC2/VPC as a permanent home for FME Desktop.

This another question that is inspired by this closely related question:
[Is there an optimum RAM configuration to use for FME Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77957/is-there-an-optimum-ram-configuration-to-use-for-fme-desktop)

Comment: I promise, that's my last FME question for today.

Comment: You need the brand NEW FME in the cloud (released 13th November 2013) . Sign up and get $250 of credits https://fmecloud.com/

Comment: I am already signed up, but the $250 doesn't go very far on the Enterprise instance (I'm looking to test&eval on an instance greater than 32GB RAM) . Enterprise  has 68GB RAM, so that was another reason I was I thought there was an optimal RAM configuration: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77957/is-there-an-optimum-ram-configuration-to-use-for-fme-desktop

Comment: Are beta's the only product available in FME Cloud?  That's pretty clever...I burn through $250 in day 1 and now I am *paying them* to beta test.  Maybe I'll ask them for more free money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's certainly possible to run Desktop on a virtual machine (whether or not it's in the cloud) and we run it on Amazon machines for all of our online training courses. To quote the installation and licensing manual:

*FME Desktop can be run on the following virtual platforms:*

- *Amazon Web Services (AWS) Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2)*
- *VMware virtual machines*

You can also run FME Server virtually as well. It's a good alternative to FME Cloud. Basically FME Cloud is us doing the setup and hosting for you, but there's no reason you can't do that work yourself and install your own FME Server. Of course the cost isn't a pay-as-you-go there (at least not for the FME Server software).

On the fact of FME Cloud being in beta right now, that's true, but we're so close to release that the differences are going to be negligible. We already did the hard-core testing before we launched.

***nb:** I do work for Safe Software*

Comment: Good to know. FME Cloud probably isn't a solution for me personally, but definitely something others should check out. Very easy to get up and running and I would agree that it is Beta in name only.

Answer (score 1):

While looking for something else, I found "Amazon Web Services (EC2)" in the list of supported platforms (under Virtualization):

http://www.safe.com/fme/fme-technology/fme-desktop/tech-specs/

So it looks like it is allowed.